# antlr alias not working in other directories

Tags: java, parsing, antlr, antlr4

I am trying to get started with antlr4.
I followed the installation tutorial from their website step by step including writing the following command:

```
alias antlr4='java -Xmx500M -cp "/usr/local/lib/antlr-4.9.2-complete.jar:$CLASSPATH" org.antlr.v4.Tool'
```

I created two Hello.g4 files, one in usr/local/lib and one in my Desktop. When I run

```
antlr4 Hello.g4
```

in lib, it works just fine. However, when I run it in the Desktop, I get

```
antlr4: command not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alias is valid only in the current session. You may need to write the first command to ~/.bashrc (depending on your system).

Comment: Thanks, do you know how I do that using a mac?

Comment: @user14545805 I haven't used a Mac. Check whether .bash_profile exists in the Home directory.

Comment: Yes, it has a path for python and conda only

Comment: Append the command to the end of .bash_profile and restart the computer.